# Vue.js nested for loop with search filter

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, search, filter

I have a JSON object with nested objects that I am iterating over to pull out data. All is working fine, but I'd like to add a search/filter implementation so that the search is being done on the second level of the nested `for` loop. I have it somewhat working but im not getting any data returned. Here is an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-s9t9o

In the HelloWorld component is where the search/filter is happening.
As you can see its not outputting the rest of the data after it passes through the searchFilter method.

To make it work without the search/filter, change the following on `line #6`:

from: `<div class="contentSingle" v-for="(c, i) in searchFilter" :key="i">`

to: `<div class="contentSingle" v-for="(c, i) in cont" :key="i">`

Anyone can think of what I can do to make this work? I need to filter by the elements inside each of the `content` inside the main data object. You can find the data object inside the `FauxData/dataContent.js` dir.

Thanks a lot.

-S

Comment: You should post relevant code in the question rather than relying exclusively on an external link. What exactly should be filtered here, the main items or the sub-items? I understand that it's the sub-items that should be used for matching purposes but that still leaves ambiguity. If a single sub-item matches then should only that sub-item be shown or the whole parent item?

Comment: Noted... If a sub-item is a match, I'd like the main index/label displayed and also that particular title and content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use methods instead of computed:

```
  methods: {
    filterValue(content) {
      return content.filter(item => {
        let itemUpper = item.content.toUpperCase();
        let searchUpper = this.search.toUpperCase();
        return itemUpper.indexOf(searchUpper) > -1;
      });
    }
  }
```

and then in HTML code:

```
  <section id="content">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" v-model="search" placeholder="Search Content...">
    <div v-for="(cont, index) in content" :key="index" class="contentWrapper">
      <h1>{{ index }}</h1>
      <div class="contentSingle" v-for="(c, i) in filterValue(cont)" :key="i">
        <h3>{{ c.title }}</h3>
        <div v-html="c.content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

**Updated**

If you want to hide the empty section, then use computed value:

```
  computed: {
    filteredData() {
      return Object.keys(this.content).reduce((a, cKey) => {
        const data = this.filterValue(this.content[cKey]);
        if (data.length) {
          a[cKey] = data;
        }
        return a;
      }, {});
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterValue(content) {
      return content.filter(item => {
        let itemUpper = item.content.toUpperCase();
        let searchUpper = this.search.toUpperCase();
        return itemUpper.indexOf(searchUpper) > -1;
      });
    }
  }
```

Use `filteredData` in outer v-for

```
  <section id="content">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" v-model="search" placeholder="Search Content...">
    <div v-for="(cont, index) in filteredData" :key="index" class="contentWrapper">
      <h1>{{ index }}</h1>
      <div class="contentSingle" v-for="(c, i) in cont" :key="i">
        <h3>{{ c.title }}</h3>
        <div v-html="c.content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Demo on [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-etsdf)

Comment: Thank you ittus. How would I hide the root/parent elements on the object that are not part of the filtered results? For example on your code if you filter using `Four Two` you get the very last title-content combo and its root/parent 'Main Four'. BUT you still see the other root/parents...how can we hide those? Does the method have to be executed in the first `for` loop?